# Автоклик при загрузке страницы

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте, возможно сделать автоклик в определенный блок/точку сразу после загрузки сайта? Если да, то как?

Comment: Зависит. Где размещается код? По чему производится клик, в том же документе где и код?

Comment: Да, код размещается в том же месте

Comment: sholkingx, пожалуйста, вставьте в свой вопрос (при помощи кнопки «Править») код страницы, где Вы хотите сделать автоклик.

Answer (score 3):

Вот так если нужно кликнуть по определенному блоку на странице.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ // функция будет выполнена при полной загрузке страницы
  setTimeout(function(){ // если нужно устанавливаем задержку выполнения действия
      $('#click-block').click(); // имитируем нажатие кнопкой мишы на блок
  },5000); // время задержки в милисикундах
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="click-block">Блок по которуму нужно кликнуть</div>
```